# How to detect click event on date cell in Google visualization.Calendar

Tags: javascript, calendar, google-visualization, visualization, graph-visualization

I have a question regarding google.visualization.Calendar. I have read the [https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/calendar#months][1] but still couldn't find any solutions

The below code is the code that I'm using for testing.

```
var dataTable=new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({type:'date', id:'Date'});
    dataTable.addColumn({type:'number',id:'Events Found'});

    dataTable.addRows([
                       [ new Date(2016, (05-1), 19), 400],
                       [ new Date(2016, 02, 23), 300],
                       [ new Date(2016, 05, 24), 300],
                       [ new Date(2016, 06, 23), 300]
                       ]);

    var chart=new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendarView'));
    var options={
            title: "Event Calendar",
            width: 500,
            height:400,
            calendar: { 
                cellSize: 5 ,
                    focusedCellColor: {
                      stroke: 'red',
                      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                      strokeWidth: 3
                    }       
            },
             /*noDataPattern: {
                   backgroundColor: '#76a7fa',
                   color: '#a0c3ff'
                 },*/


            calendar: {
                  underYearSpace: 2, 
                  yearLabel: {
                    fontName: 'Times-Roman',
                    fontSize: 32,
                    color: '#e6ecff',
                    bold: true,
                    italic: true
                  }
                }
    };

    chart.draw(dataTable,options);
```

I need to add a click event handler when user click the specific date. How to do that?

Here are the codes I tested with no results.

**code :1**

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart,'click',function(){
        alert ('click');
    });
```

**code :2**

```
google.visualization.events.trigger(dataTable, 'select', selectHandler);
    function selectHandler() {
      alert('A table row was selected');
    }
```

Any tip to solve them would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[calendar events](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/calendar#events) include `'select'`, but no `'click'`...

to use the `'select'` event, the listener must be added to the `chart`,
before it is drawn.

see following example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'date', id: 'Date'});
    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'number', id: 'Events Found'});

    dataTable.addRows([
      [ new Date(2016, (05-1), 19), 400],
      [ new Date(2016, 02, 23), 300],
      [ new Date(2016, 05, 24), 300],
      [ new Date(2016, 06, 23), 300]
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendarView'));

    var options={
      title: 'Event Calendar',
      calendar: {
        focusedCellColor: {
          stroke: 'red',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWidth: 3
        },
        underYearSpace: 2,
        yearLabel: {
          fontName: 'Times-Roman',
          fontSize: 32,
          color: '#e6ecff',
          bold: true,
          italic: true
        }
      },
    };

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
      document.getElementById('msg_div').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(chart.getSelection());
    });

    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  },
  packages:['calendar']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="calendarView"></div>
<div id="msg_div"></div>
```

Comment: Absolutely it is helpful. Thanks :) . Do you have any idea to limit the displaying moths in calendar instead of display all 12 months ?

Comment: no, I saw the question. my only idea would be to somehow cut the size short, use an overlay, or inspect / remove elements. none easy choices -- no standard options available...